# Get rows if condition is applicable else single row

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a case where I have 2 tables, `Customers` and `Transactions`.

Many customers may form a customer group (record inside `Customers` table). I need to show `Customers` and certain sums in a single row (per group that is) if all of the group's customers has a certain condition (numeric column `xCol <> 5`). If any one of them (aka at least one) has `xCol = 5`, I need to show all customers and not the group.

CUSTOMERS TABLE

```
Customer    Group       Customer Code
ALPHA   GROUP A     1
BETA    GROUP A     2
GAMMA   GROUP A     3
DELTA   GROUP B     4
LAMDA   GROUP B     5
```

TRANSACTIONS TABLE

```
Customer Code   xCol    Amount
1                   1   4
2                   1   4
3                   1   4
4                   5   1
5                   2   2
```

In the above case i will need to show these:

```
Customer    Group       Amount
-----           GROUP A     12
DELTA           GROUP B     1
LAMDA           GROUP B     2
```

Thank you in advance

Comment: Please post some sample data from these two tables and the desired output that you are looking for. This will be very helpful to explain what are you trying to do.

Comment: I've edited the initial post, Mahmoud. Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: @brd: Your desired output appears to be the opposite of what you had described - you are summarising customers by group where there is no xcol=5 and including individual customers where there is an xcol=5, the opposite of what you originally described. Which do you actually want?

Comment: @MarkBannister and tombom: Yes, indeed guys. I fixed the initial post. Thanks again.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try:

```
with cte as
(select c.*,
        t.Amount,
        max(case xCol when 5 then 1 end) over (partition by c.[Group]) xCol5
 from customers c
 left join transactions t on c.[Customer Code] = t.[Customer Code])
select case xCol5 when 1 then [Customer Code] end [Customer Code],
       [Group],
       sum(Amount) Amount
from cte
group by [Group], case xCol5 when 1 then [Customer Code] end
```

Answer (score 0):

Needs some optimization, but you can go with

```
SELECT *
  FROM (SELECT tc.CUSTOMER, tc.GROUP, tt.AMNT AS AMOUNT
          FROM CUSTOMERS tc
               JOIN TRANSACTIONS  tt
                  ON tc.CUST_CODE = tt.CUST_CODE
               JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT tc.GROUP
                       FROM CUSTOMERS  tc JOIN TRANSACTIONS  tt
                               ON tt.CUST_CODE = tc.CUST_CODE
                      WHERE tt.XCOL = 5) spgrp
                  ON spgrp.GROUP = tc.GROUP)
UNION ALL
(  SELECT '----' AS CUSTOMER, tc.GROUP, SUM (tt.AMNT) AS AMOUNT
     FROM CUSTOMERS  tc
          JOIN TRANSACTIONS  tt
             ON tc.CUST_CODE = tt.CUST_CODE
          JOIN ( (  SELECT DISTINCT GROUP FROM TEST_CUST)
                MINUS
                (SELECT DISTINCT tc.GROUP
                   FROM CUSTOMERS tc JOIN TRANSACTIONS tt
                           ON tt.CUST_CODE = tc.CUST_CODE
                  WHERE tt.XCOL = 5)) othgrp
             ON othgrp.GROUP = tc.GROUP
 GROUP BY tc.GROUP)
ORDER BY 2, 1
```